# How to set ffmpeg command line option in FFmpeg.AutoGen

Tags: c#, tcp, ffmpeg, udp, rtsp

I am trying to read/decode RTSP stream from my ip camera using **FFmpeg.AutoGen** lib. 
The server responds with error when *ffmpeg* tries to connect via UDP. 
The same thing happens when i try to connect via ffmpeg exe:

`ffmpeg -i rtsp://<url...> -vcodec h264 c:\out.mp4`

But when use *-rtsp_transport tcp* every thing works fine:

`ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://<url...> -vcodec h264 c:\out.mp4`

Can anyone suggest how to enable such options (in general, or in particular *-rtsp_transport tcp* option) in FFmpeg.AutoGen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first, you should set AVDiconary's values like below.

```
AVDictionary* opts = null;
ffmpeg.av_dict_set(&opts, "rtsp_transport", "tcp", 0);
```

second, you should change some source code in 'VideoStreamDecoder.cs' like below.

```
public VideoStreamDecoder(string url,AVDictionary* opts, AVHWDeviceType HWDeviceType = AVHWDeviceType.AV_HWDEVICE_TYPE_NONE)
....
ffmpeg.avformat_open_input(&pFormatContext, url, null, &opts);
```

then your code will work TCP
(if you have corrupted image using RTSP, above code will work too)